# SQL - getting 'out of date' rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select, where-clause

So I've got a C# client application that contains a List of object models (each of which represents a row in an MS SQL Server database table).

These contain a DateTime member called RowDate.

The database table also contains a datetime2 column called RowDate.

RowDate is basically the date and time that the row was last updated or inserted in the database.

I need a query to select rows that are 'out of date' - i.e. RowDate on the server > RowDate in the client application FOR THAT PARTICULAR ROW/OBJECT. Obviously it's not as simple as just putting `WHERE RowDate > [whatever]` in the query as there will be many dates to compare to and they all need to be compared on a row-by-row basis.

The point being to make sure the 'cached' data in the C# application is brought up to date while minimising the traffic to and from the database.

I have a few ideas how to achieve this, but they all seem very ugly, slow, inefficient, or a pain in the ass; so I'm throwing this question out here in the hope that someone can point me in the right direction.

I *COULD* always concatenate some lengthy `WHERE` clause, but that seems a bit clunky - there could be thousands of objects in the C# application, so that ends up being a very lengthy SQL query...surely there's a better way? Maybe creating some sort of temporary table in memory with some sort of intersection between that and the main table in the DB? My inexperience with SQL is showing here.

I've spent a while on google trying to look this up but I'm struggling to distill my question down into search terms...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually people use `ROW_VERSION()` or some sort of hashing to compare entire rows based on just 1 column instead of comparing every column in that row.

Comment: I think you've missed my point (or maybe I didn't explain myself clearly). `RowDate` already gets updated automatically by a trigger every time someone does an update or insert (vaguely similar to `ROW_VERSION()`). That's not the issue; I just don't know how to start coding the SQL to compare the client object model with the database. Or have I misunderstood you?

Answer (score 0):

The way I usually do it is refresh the objects as they need to be refreshed.  For instance, if you have an object in memory that represents a row in a table, you only seek to refresh that object when you know (based on your application/business logic) that you require up-to-date data (e.g. in your case based on the `RowDate`).

So instead of approaching it from the database side (i.e. "get me all rows where the `RowDate` has changed compared with the objects in memory), you could employe a "lazy load" technique where you approach it from the application side: only when you are using an object that needs to be refreshed do you check the DB to see if it has an new `RowDate`.

Comment: That will work for some of the situations in the application, but not in others. For example, in one area there is a large (~2000 rows) list that the user wants to be able browse through; the only way to do that (that I can see) would be to query the rows as the user scrolls down. That's going to slow down the UI too much.

Comment: @JezClark -- Is it really going to slow it down?  How else are you going to find out that the data has changed?

Comment: @JezClark -- In my experience, it's surprisingly fast.  Though I have a fast connection between our users and the DB server.

Comment: The application can be run over the internet and the client's upstream is horrific. They won't fork out for a better connection though, so unfortunately, yes, it does slow things down a lot. It can take a couple of seconds to select 20 rows...

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate.  I don't have any other tips to offer then, unfortunately.